# Angular directive doesn't work properly inside an HTML table

Tags: angularjs, html-table, directive

I'm trying to use an AngularJS (1.2) directive to create row cells inside an HTML Table and I don't understand why Angular inserts the directive result as first child of 'body' instead of replacing the original directive element?

Here is the HTML markup:

```
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>col1</th>
          <th>col2</th>
          <th>col3</th>
          <th>col4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <my-directive></my-directive>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
```

And the directive:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = ['value1','value2','value3','value4'];
});

app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope:false,
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var html = angular.element('<tr></tr>');
            angular.forEach(scope.data, function(value, index) {
                html.append('<td>'+value+'</td>');
            });
            element.replaceWith(html);
        }            
    };
});
```

Please use the Plunker link below to see the result:
http://plnkr.co/edit/zc00RIUHWNYW36lY5rgv?p=preview

Comment: For replace to work, use a template.

Comment: We can not always use template property (my code has been simplified for the example). In addition, the replace property works well with other tags. I've just the problem with html-table.

Comment: Browsers will automatically discard improper or unexpected tags in tables. In order to make your directive work, use it as an attribute instead of an element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to work better if you dont restrict the directive to be an element:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        scope:false,
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var html = angular.element('<tr></tr>');
            angular.forEach(scope.data, function(value, index) {
                html.append('<td>'+value+'</td>');
            });
            element.replaceWith(html);
        }            
    };
});

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr my-directive></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```